# how to make a request music file mp3 and get a response to AudioTag or maybe there is a library to search for a song from an mp3 file

Tags: python, json, parsing, audio, request

How to make a request with an mp3 file and get a response with the name of the song in https://ru.audiotag.info/ and get music name.

```
import requests  
**import** json

url = "https://ru.audiotag.info/ "

msg = ""  
data = {"prompt": }

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data)).json()  
answer = response.get("replies")  
print(\*answer)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.